# Python CSV read file and select columns and write to new CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file which has certain columns which I need to extract. One of those columns is a text string from which I need to extract the first and last items. I have a print statement in a for loop which get exactly what I need but cannot figure out how to either get that data into a list or dict. Not sure which is the best to use.

Code so far:

```
f1 = open ("report.csv","r") # open input file for reading 
users_dict = {}
with open('out.csv', 'wb') as f: # output csv file

writer = csv.writer(f)
with open('report.csv','r') as csvfile: # input csv file
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print row['User Name'],row['Address'].split(',')[0],row['Last Login DateTime'],row['Address'].split(',')[7]
        users_dict.update(row)
        #users_list.append(row['Address'].split(','))
        #users_list.append(row['Last Login DateTime'])
        #users_list.append(row[5].split(',')[7])

print users_dict

f1.close()
```

Input from file:

```
User Name,Display Name,Login Name,Role,Last Login DateTime,Address,Application,AAA,Exchange,Comment
SUPPORT,SUPPORT,SUPPORT,124,2015-05-29 14:32:26,"Test Company,Bond St,London,London,1111 111,GB,test@test.com,IS",,,LSE,
```

Output on print:

```
SUPPORT Test Company 2015-05-29 14:32:26 IS
```

Comment: Is this the output you want? If not, what output *do* you want?

Comment: The output is exactly how I want it, its getting it into a list/dict or written to a new csv I can't get working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some testing I finally get the line to write the csv file:

```
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow([row['User Name'],row['Address'].split(',')[0],row['Last Login DateTime'],row['Address'].split(',')[7]])
```

Comment: I have to use indices to make it work in python3

Answer (score 1):

Using this code, I've got the line you need:

```
import csv
f1 = open ("report.csv","r") # open input file for reading 
users_dict = {}
with open('out.csv', 'wb') as f: # output csv file
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    with open('report.csv','r') as csvfile: # input csv file
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            print row['User Name'],row['Address'].split(',')[0],row['Last Login DateTime'],row['Address'].split(',')[7]
            users_dict.update(row)
            #users_list.append(row['Address'].split(','))
            #users_list.append(row['Last Login DateTime'])
            #users_list.append(row[5].split(',')[7])

    print users_dict

f1.close()
```

The only changes:

- Including the `import csv` at the top.
- Indenting the code just after the `with open('out.csv' ......`

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry I missed the import csv when copying/pasting the code to the question. The problem I am having is getting all the rows of data as per the print command below either into a variable or written to a second csv. The print command is exactly the data i want.

Comment: print row['User Name'],row['Address'].split(',')[0],row['Last Login DateTime'],row['Address'].split(',')[7]